# NSB ScriptBuilderTask cannot resolve assembly of own nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-core, nservicebus, saga, nservicebus-sagas

We have a microservice architecture and share some code between our services using a nuget package called "HC.Framework".

When i try to build a solution that is using this nuget package (that has all the configs for NSB and stuff) i get the following exception:

```
1>MSBUILD : error : SqlPersistenceTask: An unhandled exception occurred:
1>MSBUILD : error : Exception:
1>MSBUILD : error : Failed to resolve assembly: 'HC.Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
1>MSBUILD : error : StackTrace:
1>MSBUILD : error :    at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
1>MSBUILD : error :    at CecilExtensions.FindInTypeHierarchy[T](TypeDefinition type, Func`2 search)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at SagaDefinitionReader.TryGetCoreSagaDefinition(TypeDefinition type, SagaDefinition& definition)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at AllSagaDefinitionReader.GetSagas(Action`2 logger)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at SagaWriter.WriteScripts(BuildSqlDialect dialect)
1>MSBUILD : error :    at ScriptGenerator.Generate()
1>MSBUILD : error :    at InnerTask.Execute()
1>MSBUILD : error :    at NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql.SqlPersistenceScriptBuilderTask.Execute()
1>MSBUILD : error : Source:
1>MSBUILD : error : NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql.ScriptBuilderTask
1>MSBUILD : error :
```

I'm not sure what the issue is here? Below is a snippet of a saga class:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NServiceBus;
using HC.Swatson.Processor.Saga.Command;
using HC.Framework.NSB;
using HC.Swatson.Application.Command;
using HC.Integration.ReplyMessages.Sendgrid;

namespace HC.Swatson.Processor.Saga
{
    public class SendWrongPredictionEmailSD : BaseSagaData<SendWrongPredictionEmailCMD>
    {
        public SendWrongPredictionEmailSD() : base(totalSteps: 2) { }
    }

    public class SendWrongPredictionEmailSAGA :
        Saga<SendWrongPredictionEmailSD>,
        IAmStartedByMessages<SendWrongPredictionEmailCMD>,
        IHandleMessages<ReplyMessage<SendWrongPredictionEmail2CMD>>,
        IHandleMessages<EmailHasBeenSentRM>
    {
...
```

We also specify the following configuration in the HC.Framework package:

```
[assembly: SqlPersistenceSettings(
    MsSqlServerScripts = true,
    MySqlScripts = false,
    OracleScripts = false,
    PostgreSqlScripts = false,
    ProduceOutboxScripts = true,
    ProduceSagaScripts = true,
    ProduceSubscriptionScripts = true,
    ProduceTimeoutScripts = true
    )]
```

The only maybe helpfull info i can think of is that we are upgrading from .net5 to 6, this might be related?

Any ideas on why this might ocure is welcome!

EDIT:

So after some more looking into it. If i run the scripts manually with the dotnet tool the scripts generate fine. This seems to be a issue/bug with NSB so i've openend a ticket with them.

Comment: The NServiceBus script builder seems to be looking at your messages, which should be pocos (simple classes) but don't seem to be simple classes. It should throw an error but apparently crashes when trying to load some assembly to figure out what the SQL script should be. There's not enough information here to go by. I'd suggest opening up a support case with Particular Software. They might be able to look at what code you have and have suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt thanks for your comment, i've done some further investigation and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just install NServiceBus in your project where you want to use it

Comment: Hi Elias, Thank you for your suggestion but we want to try and avoid having Nuget references twice. (once in HC.Reference and once in the project itself).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).